# How to create file in random directory

Tags: random, terminal, command

I'm trying to make the terminal make a bunch of files (it's on a loop), with random names, random size, random data, in random directories. By random directories I mean they could be anywhere on the computer

Comment: Sounds like an exceptionally bad idea to clean up afterwards. Also, you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a starting point is this script

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
    # Create random file
    #
    data=$(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 < /dev/urandom)
    random_file=$(mktemp)
    echo "$data" > "$random_file"

    echo "Created $random_file file, with data=$data"

    # Create random directory
    #
    random_dir=$(mktemp -d)

    echo "Created $random_dir directory"
done
```

output:

```
Created /tmp/tmp.Toet7Wn7bz file, with data= 4221696069
Created /tmp/tmp.kc9OLaX84U directory
Created /tmp/tmp.S2OQ8Wh6Iz file, with data=  172066121
Created /tmp/tmp.d1oFQ4DINx directory
Created /tmp/tmp.wGl42vpRLc file, with data= 3188097801
Created /tmp/tmp.xbAhMUFAZi directory
Created /tmp/tmp.4dI5M7amYL file, with data= 1085037810
Created /tmp/tmp.vAMAg39pjK directory
Created /tmp/tmp.AXP6yztDMj file, with data= 2348013838
Created /tmp/tmp.Qc5kyZtmnn directory
```

It generates 5 random files storing a random number and 5 random directories.

This is an initial idea only (-> the directories and files are not nested, etc.) but I guess this should be possible to extend this initial script.

Comment: Does this make random directories? Or is it putting the files in a randomly selecteddirectory?

Comment: `mktemp -d`  creates a random directory. You can use another destination with `mktemp -d ~/some_path/nameXXXX` -> the X are going to be remplaced by random char. The missing feature of my script is that random directories are not populated by random file/dir. But this is possible at the expense of some extra work.

Comment: I mean like would it be possible to put it in a random directory that already exists